# installing theano package on windows

Tags: python, easy-install

I am trying to install the theano package on my windows machine. I seem to have problem installing pip by typing : easy_install pip

The python shell complains: SyntaxError: invalid syntax   on pip.

I am trying to install it on EPD and 
I have imported numpy before typing easy_install pip.
I have been using the guidelines provided in :
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`easy_install` is a program that you should run from a system shell, not from within Python. It's usually located in `<your python folder>/Scripts/`, though I've not verified that this is true for the Enthought distribution.